# OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer [RSA decrypt]

Tags: python-2.7, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to decrypt a message using a public key:

I know that is not the standard but in my case the encryption is done with a private key and decryption with a public key. Server encrypts data, sends it to clients. Clients have public key, and can decrypt data from the server.

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAu8rtXhPxSojY7NyHiOlo
XkVCAwhCaMU7rZleDOxsXIqS4zzEkD87r2DujuCWD/6Fummxem0al8y4gD5M4b4O
K+m7qDJ5K4NCB8eW5D/DQ+dIa63sDroyrmJqtLMOKuWxZqYJXEM6vqDm1vKAZpBv
A04CX5zyN7O3G6rB2mVa2Io+OJXxNx/J7ebe20TE5w5zKqQR+LUs9tVYPrOKDmVj
7b8pv9hbSmK+t+x/Z7von2Fr6WfdqFW/VkD09Cu2r5yc2klyEcdIIDwN5krBpdN4
Gon/BkyD+t1lwmpZOUXvKzWyOPuHazEXcKaAe3PTzVDX5ubwOfiiUis87+ekpoHa
mwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and this is the portion of python code which is used to decrypt the message:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import json
import codecs
import base64
from base64 import b64decode

def read(response_json):
    with open(response_json) as r:
        data = json.load(r)
        session = data["output"]["session"]
        return session

def decrypt(session):
    cert = open('publicKey\key.txt', "rb").read()
    publicKey = RSA.importKey(cert)
    decrypted_info = publicKey.decrypt(session)

    return decrypted_info
```

Shortly the script get a file json in which there is a section called 'session' which is crypted and to read it correctly i need to decrypt via the public key posted above but when i try to decrypt i reach the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\decripting.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(r.decrypt(session))
  File "C:\Users\Fabio\...", line 16, in decrypt
    decrypted_info = publicKey.decrypt(session)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 174, in decrypt
    return pubkey.pubkey.decrypt(self, ciphertext)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py", line 93, in decrypt
    plaintext=self._decrypt(ciphertext)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 237, in _decrypt
    cp = self.key._blind(ciphertext, r)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py", line 43, in _blind
    return m * pow(r, self.e, self.n)
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer
```

I don't know really how to resolve this problem, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: "I'm trying to decrypt a message using a public key ..." decryption is done with a private key.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I know but in my case the encryption is done with a private key and decryption with a public key.
Server encrypts data, sends it to clients.
Clients have public key, and can decrypt data from the server.

Comment: @JamesKPolk RSA can work either way. For instance, if I want to authenticate that *you're* the owner of a certain public key, I can ask you to send me some data *encrypted* with your private key, and I can verify by decrypting with your public key.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you try to decrypt a string instead of bytes.